# Incremented Instance variable is not available to the next thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am very new to threads. So please forgive my ignorance if it is a very basic question.
Basically, I am trying to write a list of employees to an excel workbook.
So in the below class, `startUp` method is called only once. Whereas the write method is called multiple times from 10 different threads.

```
@Component
class MyEmployeeWriter{
priavte int rowNum; // To start with, the rowNum is 0 here

public void startUp(Employees employee)
{
    // some logic ...
    this.rowNum++; //now rowNum is 1
}


public void write(Employees employees)
{
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.createRow(this.rowCount); //here for all the 10 threads the, rowNum is 1
    // Some more logic here...

    this.rowCount++;
}

}
```

The issue I face is, for all the 10 threads `this.rowCount` is 1. The incremented`rowCount` is not available for the next thread.

> **Trial 1:**

I used the `volatile` keyword for rowNum. That also did not work.

> **Trial 2:**

I tried changing the rowNum as `Integer(Wrapper class)` and added a synchronized block on it. That did not work either.

```
synchronized(this.rowNum) // I changed rowNum from int to Integer.
{
  // Some logic here
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `AtomicInteger`? And are you certain that all the threads are using the same instance of `MyEmployeeWriter`? If they're all using independent instances, that would explain everything... (If you could provide a [mcve], that would make it easier to help you.)

Comment: Firstly, I should say that I am a huge fan of yours. :-) 
Now, I am using @Component annotation with no Scope mentioned, therefore by default, it takes Singleton. So there should be only one instance. I have updated my question now. 
I have not tried AtomicInteger. I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Without the context of how things are being created, it's hard to tell, to be honest. A [mcve] showing the problem would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is generally to make an `AtomicInteger` variable. However, it sounds like you're making a different mistake, and you actually have 10 instances of MyEmployeeWriter.

Note that your synchronized trick does nothing whatever; Integer is immutable: each time you increment it, it's a different instance, and 'synchronized(X)' has no interaction whatsoever with any other synchronized(Y), unless X and Y are both references to the same object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is only one instance as I have used @Component annotation.(Sorry I missed to add this to the question earlier). I will try using AtomicInteger and get back to you.

Comment: AtomicInteger variable was the way to go. It fixed my issue. Thanks for your Answer :-)